# On-going Rolling 12 month sum for KPI

Tags: sql

I have been asked to produce 2 KPI charts which give a Rolling 12 month percentage of:
1.Percentage of hours lost due to long term sickness against hours available 
2.Percentage of hours lost due to short term sickness against hours available

As you can see in the image below I have the totals as per the last day of the month up until the day the KPI is viewed. (see as at date) This is saved as a view.

[KPI View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SbtF8.jpg)

Can anybody now help me with displaying the data so that it totals up the hours as per the last 12 months? once I have these the percentages I can do, its the totalling the hours over the rolling 12 months I am struggling with.

e.g 
if ran today (23/03/2016)
march 2016 would be the sum of all the results from april 2015 to 23 march 2016
Feb 2016 would be the sum of all the results from march 2015 to 29th feb 2016
and so on...

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider window function. For example, generating running total of AvailableHours:

```
    sum(AvailableHours)over(order by calendarshortyearmonth asc) as run_total_AvailableHours
```